# Unable to change background of div containing unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simply want to change the background dynamically, don't seem to be able to do it, what am I missing here? I should clarify, that it is the background of the container div I am trying to change...

```
$('#container').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('bgchange');
});

$('#container ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('bgchange');
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ed7zs9w/1/

Comment: Your example works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id identifier is more specific than the class identifier for the container css so it gets overridden. Therefore if you want to override for the container and have it also change color add `!important`. Example http://jsfiddle.net/e5bgsh3v/

Answer (score 0):

JSFIDDLE DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/7ed7zs9w/4/

This is happening because you have background-color mentioned in the `#container` selector in the CSS which has the higher hierarchy than the class `bgchange`. Hence it never changes.

Make the following changes:

HTML

```
<div id="container" class="redbg"> //add class redbg here
```

CSS

```
#container{
    height: 150px; //remove background-color here
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.bgchange{
    background-color: blue;
}
.redbg{
    background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#container').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('redbg bgchange'); // toggle between 2 classes instead of 1
});

$('#container ul li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // add this here
    $(this).toggleClass('bgchange');
});
```